# help proving an binomial identity about catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

I need help proving the following identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = \binom{2n+1}{n}.$$

It has to do with the Catalan numbers and Dyck walks.
Notice that $$\frac{1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k}$$ is the Catalan number $C_k$.

Comment: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65944/proving-this-identity-sum-k-frac1k-binom2k-2k-1-binom2n-2k1n-k-b?rq=1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65944/proving-this-identity-sum-k-frac1k-binom2k-2k-1-binom2n-2k1n-k-b?rq=1)

Comment: you can use the symmetry of the binomials together with cauchy convolution and the gf of the catalan numbers

Comment: outch...a duplicate...i will remove my answer...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer based upon generating functions. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[z^k]\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}[t^{n-k}](1+t)^{2n-2k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[t^n](1+t)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}\right)^k[z^k]\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag{2}\\
> &=[t^n](1+t)^{2n}\cdot\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{4t}{(1+t)^2}}}\tag{3}\\
> &=[t^n](1+t)^{2n+1}\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{2n+1}{n}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. Here we use the generating function $\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}$ of the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*. We also set the limit to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply  the rule 
  $$
  [t^{p-q}]A(t)=[t^p]t^qA(t)
  $$
  We    also do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k [z^k]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we do some simplifications.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $[t^n]$.