# Catalan number's combinatoric proof

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers

prove a combinatoric proof
the identity:  $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} $$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = \binom{2n+1}{n} $

I tried using Catalan numbers: and one of the formulas for them:

$C_{n} = $$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$
but it lead nowhere.

I tried opening the binom and maybe simplifying but it wasn't any good

Comment: If I were a betting man, I would bet that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: If the question is "Any help?" - then this is not really a mathematical question. Please provide a good context, and really show the own progress. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question to know how to provide a good context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving this identity $\sum_k\frac{1}{k}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\binom{2n-2k+1}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n-1}$ using lattice paths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65944/proving-this-identity-sum-k-frac1k-binom2k-2k-1-binom2n-2k1n-k-b)